# C# application can not load embedded text resources

Tags: c#, .net-assembly, embedded-resource, streamreader

I can not read embedded resource text file.
I keep getting this error when i start my C# application

```
    Unhandled Exception: System.ArgumentNullException: Value cannot be null.
Parameter name: stream
   at System.IO.StreamReader..ctor(Stream stream, Encoding encoding, Boolean detectEncodingFromByteOrderMarks, Int32 bufferSize, Boolean leaveOpen)
   at System.IO.StreamReader..ctor(Stream stream, Encoding encoding)
   at abcdefg.abcdefgh.LoadResource(String ResourcePath)
   at abcdefg.abcdefgh.<Main>b__0()
   at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart_Context(Object state)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
   at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart()
```

This is the method:

```
public static string LoadResource(string ResourcePath)
{
    var assembly = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly();
    using (var stream = assembly.GetManifestResourceStream(ResourcePath))
    {
        using (var reader = new StreamReader(stream, Encoding.UTF8))
        {
            return reader.ReadToEnd();
        }
    }
}
```

This is how am i compiling the executable using CODEDOM:

```
                    Dictionary<string, string> provOptions = new Dictionary<string, string>();
                provOptions.Add("CompilerVersion", "v4.0");
                CodeDomProvider provider = CodeDomProvider.CreateProvider("CSharp", provOptions);

                CompilerParameters parameters = new CompilerParameters();
                parameters.ReferencedAssemblies.Add("System.Net.dll");
                parameters.ReferencedAssemblies.Add("System.Windows.dll");
                parameters.ReferencedAssemblies.Add("System.Net.Http.dll");
                parameters.ReferencedAssemblies.Add("System.Management.dll");
                parameters.ReferencedAssemblies.Add("Microsoft.CSharp.dll");
                parameters.ReferencedAssemblies.Add("System.Data.dll");
                parameters.ReferencedAssemblies.Add("System.Deployment.dll");
                parameters.ReferencedAssemblies.Add("System.Xml.Linq.dll");
                parameters.ReferencedAssemblies.Add("System.Data.DataSetExtensions.dll");
                parameters.ReferencedAssemblies.Add("System.Data.dll");


                var assemblies = AppDomain.CurrentDomain
                        .GetAssemblies()
                        .Where(a => !a.IsDynamic)
                        .Select(a => a.Location);

                parameters.ReferencedAssemblies.AddRange(assemblies.ToArray());
                parameters.GenerateExecutable = true;
                parameters.OutputAssembly = Output;
                parameters.CompilerOptions = "/utf8output /warnaserror- /debug- /optimize+ /unsafe+ /target:exe /platform:x86";
                parameters.TreatWarningsAsErrors = false;
                parameters.EmbeddedResources.Add(resfile);
                CompilerResults results = provider.CompileAssemblyFromSource(parameters, mainScript);
```

The resource path format i am using is: `abcdefg.Resource1.txt`

Comment: Disregarding any other problem. Have you assured your self beyond all reasonable doubt the resource exists and your `ResourcePath` is correct? If so, its now time to prove it to us the resources exist and your path is correct and you are targeting the right assembly

Comment: Most likely you did not include the file as an embedded resource. Select the file in solution explorer, press F4 and under "Build Action" select "Embedded resource". The other possibility is that you have the path wrong.

Comment: The resource path is the complete namespace-style name of the resource. For example, if you have a root namespace "MyApp" and a resource file named "Template.html" in a folder named "Templates", the resource name would be "MyApp.Templates.Template.html".

Comment: The resource path format i am using is: `abcdefg.Resource1.txt`
Eg.: `namespace.filename.fileextension`

Comment: Use GetManifestResourceNames to enumerate resources and make sure it's there under the name you expect

Comment: I checked if i included the resource file using dot peek and it was there.

Comment: It's not there, apparently. You possibly have a multi assembly project and the GetExecutingAssembly possibly points to wrong assembly depending on where you call it from

Comment: I do not have multi assembly, i am just compiling c# console app with embedded resources as and i am using code dom. If i am wrong please correct me.

Comment: I tried getting all resources and i see the resource there using:
`string[] resNames = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetManifestResourceNames();
foreach (string resName in resNames)
    Console.WriteLine(resName);`
But the reading does not work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed it by using this code, it loops trough all resources and chooses that one i want:

```
string[] resNames = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetManifestResourceNames();
    foreach (string resName in resNames)
    {
        if (resName == ("Resource1.txt"))
        {
            Assembly assembly = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly();
            string resourcename = assembly.GetManifestResourceNames().Single(str => str.EndsWith(resName));
            Stream stream = assembly.GetManifestResourceStream(resourcename);
            StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(stream, Encoding.UTF8);
            string output = reader.ReadToEnd();
            reader.Dispose();
            stream.Dispose();
        }
    }
```

Comment: It's not a production quality code. Calling GetManifestResourceNames twice is definitely not necessary.